# How do I search emails sent from the authorized account with the Office365 API v2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, office365, faraday

I'm using faraday and have a setup for grabbing messages from the authorized account. I have no trouble grabbing incoming messages, but when I go to grab sent messages I get an empty response when I know that the account has sent messages.

Basically, what I need is to retrieve a list emails that the user has sent.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
from_conn = Faraday.new(:url => "https://outlook.office.com") do |faraday|
    faraday.response :logger
    faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
  end

# Then from:
from_response = from_conn.get do |request|
  request.url "/api/v2.0/Me/Messages?$search=%22from:#{user_email}%22&$select=SentDateTime,ToRecipients,From,Subject,Body"
  request.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{token['token']}"
  request.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
  request.headers['X-AnchorMailbox'] = user_email
end
```

And here is the parsed response body:

```
[
  [0] {
    "@odata.context" => "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me/Messages(SentDateTime,ToRecipients,From,Subject,Body)",
             "value" => []
  }
]
```

It's generating a request URI of `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Me/Messages?%24search=%22from%3Adr_dickdorkins%40outlook.com%22&%24select=SentDateTime%2CToRecipients%2CFrom%2CSubject%2CBody`.

I've tried searching in the SentItems folder like so:

```
request.url "/api/v2.0/Me/Folders/SentItems$search=%22sender:#{user_email}%22"
```

But any permutation that I thought of to search folders yields this error:

```
[0] {
    "error" => {
           "code" => "RequestBroker-ParseUri",
        "message" => "Resource not found for the segment 'Folders'."
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure what else to try--any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs, that doesn't look like the proper URL format to specify the folder in your last attempt. Excerpt from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#get-a-message-collection-rest :

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/{folder_id}/messages
```

> folder_id - string - The folder ID, or the Inbox, Drafts, SentItems, or DeletedItems well-known folder name, if you're getting messages from a specific folder. Specifying AllItems would return all messages from the entire mailbox

You should try changing this url to:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/SentItems/messages/?$select=SentDateTime,ToRecipients,From,Subject,Body
```

(It looks as if it's expecting **MailFolders** resource name instead of  **Folders**) Also, before ruling it out a problem with the request built by `faraday` , you should check what the api is returning with something like `advanced rest client`, curl or some other REST client that lets you set the headers, then bring those settings to the rails side of things.

Comment: That's it! In true SO fashion I came across the same solution after I posted the question and was just about to post the solution. You're definitely right though, it's all in the docs, I just had to look harder.

Comment: It happens - I think some people even have claimed to post a question in SO just to find the same question answered years ago... by themselves. Cheers!